# How to overcome MIME Type in PHP codeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, mime

I am trying to create an dynamic html content when requested from other website. But it returns MIME type error, How do I solve this issue

Process I'm following is script tag is shared to the user website

```
<script https://www.mywebsite.com/Home/get_html/NDc='></script>
```

the concept is user have to embed this script tag in his footer content
and the website is Live,

userwebsite request to link which generate's

```
document.write("<div style='position:fixed;z-index:9999999; bottom:2px; left:20px;'><a href='https://www.mywebsite.com/dCertificate/NDc=' target='_blank'><img oncontextmenu='return false;'  src='https://www.mywebsite.com/i
```

mage/shield/transparent/image_name.png' style='width:40%'>");

But this Returning me error like this 
Refused to execute script from 'https://www.mywebiste.com/somewhere/image/NDc=' 
because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

while searching I came to know this may be over come using .htacess

but could not find any releavant solution

here is my .htacess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^info/(.*)\.php$ Home.php?slot=$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mywebiste.com\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebiste.com/$1 [R,L]
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Main Site"
AuthUserFile "/home/myweb/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
require valid-user
```

How to disbale MIME type error.

I found this
 [How should I create embed code to display my photos on someone else's website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541881/how-should-i-create-embed-code-to-display-my-photos-on-someone-elses-website)

This says solve problem by adding Rewirite rule agains the filename.php but unfortunately returns same error

Comment: Use HTTP correctly.

Comment: can you Please elaborate what you mean to say using HTTP correctly sir

Comment: it appears you are using a `<script>` tag to request `HTML`. Since this is not really the intent of a script tag, a MIME type error is created because the browser expects to see executable code but it doesn't. I recommend you send HTML as HTML, not try to disguise it as something else. You'll have nothing but trouble.

Comment: actually that was the best way i could request html @RandyCasburn isn't there a way I could make this MIME type executable and get this thing done